# Unmatched Disk Size Partition

Tags: mount, fdisk

In Centos 7 I see this (virtualized machine on a IaaS):

```
root@hongo developer]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/vda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos    
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
/dev/vda1   *        2048    33554431    16776192   83  Linux 
/dev/vda2        33554432    41943039     4194304   82  Linux swap / Solaris  

[root@hongo developer]# df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on   
/dev/vda1        16G  4.3G   11G  29% /    
devtmpfs        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev    
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm 
tmpfs           3.9G   65M  3.8G   2% /run
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
tmpfs           782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/0 
tmpfs           782M     0  782M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Why I see only 11G reserved to / ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your partitions are total 34 GB. Could it be that you have unallocated space on the drive? If so, try simply expanding the partition.
I would like to have simply commented this as it is just a guess and doesn't solve the problem, but I don't have the reputation to do so. My apologies.

Comment: This is virtualized hd in cloud. I think I can't resize a mounted partiont, can I?

Comment: I don't think so, now that you mention it. I'm relatively new to cloud computing, but is it perhaps possible to attach a new drive with an OS (even just live gparted), boot from that, then resize your vda from that?